# Angular2, Ionic2 error: has no exported member 'AlertController'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I tried this in my code:

`import {NavController, AlertController, Toast, Loading} from 'ionic-angular';`

then in Constructor:

```
constructor(public nav: NavController, public authData: AuthData, 
                public adminData: AdminData, public formBuilder: FormBuilder, 
                public alertController: AlertController) {
```

But, I'm getting this error over console!

> project_directory/node_modules/ionic-angular/index
>
> has no exported member 'AlertController'

Answer (score 7):

This is a beta 11 breaking change.

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#steps-to-upgrade-to-beta-11

However, I'm running beta 11 and still getting the error. :/

**- UPDATE -**

First, check you package.json file and make sure the following are using rc4. Mine was on rc5.

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
```

Second, go into your node_modules folder and delete ionic_angular. I'm sure you could run an uninstall or something but this worked.

Third, update ionic globally

```
npm install -g ionic@beta
```

Then, run

```
npm install
```

Done!

Note: you might have to restart your IDE for it to stop yelling at you but the code will run.

Comment: npm install ionic@beta works when you don't want the node modules handled globally.  Also, good call on restarting the IDE to get the errors cleaned up.

Comment: you will also need to add    `"@angular/forms": "0.2.0",`

Answer (score 2):

I'm using **Alert** now, instead of **AlertController** and this worked for me!

Comment: Alert is the old way see: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#overlays